# How to create fast template engine?

Tags: javascript, templates

I'm making a template engine. Can you tell me the most efficient way to make it? Just put me in right direction. Of course, I can use .replace() method, but will it be fast with about 50 template tags and 1000 length text?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please, have a look at this [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Although this tutorial is not specifically written for a template engine, I think it will put you in a good direction to creating one: http://www.nixtu.info/2011/12/how-to-write-css-preprocessor-using.html